# Php Glob is missing from Registered PHP Streams

Tags: php, centos, glibc, iconv

I have compile php on centos server on both i386 and x86_64.
On centos x86_64 it work fine it display glob in Registered PHP Streams 
But on i386 it doesnt display glob in Registered PHP Streams

Here is the another diff from phpinfo

> On i386 :   iconv
>
> iconv support     enabled iconv implementation    unknown iconv library
>   version   unknown
>
> on X86_64:
>       iconv
>
> iconv support     enabled iconv implementation    glibc iconv library
>   version   2.12

On both server my glibc version is same.

Comment: Glob stream wrapper didn't become standard equipment until 5.3

Comment: I am trying to compile PHP 5.3.25 latest one.